# Cannot setup remote connection to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008r2-express

I've installed the server on a windows 7 64bits PC, the download from MS was for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express x64 with management tools. Firewall is open port 1433 for SQL Server and Management Studio (just in case). All SQL Server services have been configured (including named pipes and TCP/IP and point to the correct port).

From the configuration tool I cannot start SQL Server agent.

When I try and start Management Studio the login fails (windows auth and SQL Server auth)

All the solutions that I could find to a problem similar to mine involves starting Management Studio and enabling remote connection.

If I could this either programmatically (c#.net / ado.net) or modify a key in the registry I would be a happy camper

Thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: When you set up SQL Express, did you add your login to the administrators group? Who did you set the service to run as?

Comment: Also: the express versions do **not** include SQL Server agent...